# Why does my code print out a snippet of .data messages, not a number?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, emu8086

Here's the code: https://pastebin.com/Fbjr4hKU
I am writing a program, which turns a given hex number into bin number. It works by putting the first digit the user entered from a string into AL, turning it into bits using SHL and ROL, then rols to the end of AL if its a 1 or a 0, and prints acordingly. Yet my program prints out "latas yra:" and I dont know why it does that. Any help?

Here's the code: https://pastebin.com/Fbjr4hKU

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data
start   db "Iveskite ilga sesioliktaini skaiciu:", 10, 13, "$"
enteris db 10, 13, "$"
buferis db 255
nusk    db ?
simb    db 255 dup (?)
rezult  db 10, 13, "Rezultatas yra: $"

.code
  pradzia:
MOV ax, @data
MOV ds, ax

MOV ah, 9
MOV dx, offset start
INT 21h

MOV ah, 0Ah
MOV dx, offset buferis
INT 21h


MOV ah, 9
MOV dx, offset rezult
INT 21h                          

MOV bx, offset simb
MOV cl, nusk
MOV ch, 0           ;registre cl yra Ä¯vestÅ³ simboliÅ³ kiekis

CMP cx, 0
JE Pabaiga

PUSH cx
MOV SI, offset buffer+2;  



ciklas:
CMP CL, 0
JE Pabaiga
MOV AL, [SI]

CMP AL, 3Ah
JB core

CMP AL, 47h
JNAE raide

skaicius:
    JMP core

raide:
    SUB AL, 55

core:
    SHL AL, 4
    rol AL,1
    rol AL,1
    rol AL,1
    rol AL,1
    MOV CX, 4
loop1:
     rol AL,1
     and AL, 1
    CMP AL, 1h
    ADD AL, 49
    MOV DL, AL
    MOV AL, 2
    INT 21h
     dec cx
     jnz loop1


Pabaiga:
MOV ah, 4Ch
MOV al, 0
INT 21h
END pradzia
```

Yet my program prints out "latas yra:" and I dont know why it does that. Any help?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do but for example in `loop1` you destroy `al` so in subsequent iterations it can't do anything sensible.

Comment: @jester Why is it destroyed?

Comment: Because you do `MOV AL, 2`? Also this code doesn't even assemble because `buffer` is not defined. Please make sure you post your actual code. Incidentally, you should load `AH` not `AL` with the function code. Then it at least prints four ones for me :)

Comment: @Jester This is my whole code, and it assembles for me in EMU8086. And doesn't ` buferis db 255 ` define the buffer?

Comment: No? That defines `buferis` not `buffer` that you reference in `MOV SI, offset buffer+2`. It should not assemble.

Comment: @Jester Yeah, sorry. Changed the typo, yet for me it prints out not 1, but a smiley face (ascii code 2), why is that? (After I changed the function to use AH instead of AL)

Comment: It can't really print ascii code 2. Anyway you are isolating the bits wrong, and you are printing them wrong too.  `add al, 49` is adding to `'1'` instead of `'0'` and your `cmp` has no effect at all.

Comment: @Jester I changed my loop1 to `loop1:
   rol AL,1
         and AL, 1
  ADD AH, 48 
  
  MOV DL, AH
  MOV AH, 2
  INT 21h  
  
         dec cx
         jnz loop1` yet now whatever i put in i get 9222 out

Comment: `ADD AH, 48` is wrong obviously `AH` is not set first time around. Subsequently it will be `2` and that's what you get printed.

Comment: @Jester `core:
  rol AL,1
  rol AL,1
  rol AL,1
  rol AL,1
  MOV CX, 4
 loop1:
   rol AL,1
         and AL, 1 
  MOV AH, AL
  ADD AH, 48
  
  MOV DL, AH
  MOV AH, 2
  INT 21h  
  
         dec cx
         jnz loop1` Made my code like this, and it works in my opinion good the first time but not the following times, why is that?

Comment: It doesn't work because `and al, 1` destroys the rest of the bits. Insert a `push ax` before you do `and al, 1` and a `pop ax` after the `int 21h`.

Comment: If `SHL AL, 4` assembles (requiring 186 for `shl reg, imm8` but I think emu8086 allows it anyway because its convenient), so will `rol al, 4`.  Of course that's pointless, just `and al, 0Fh` instead of shifting left and then rotating back to knock off the high bits.  *Use a debugger to single-step your code*; emu8086 has a debugger built-in